# Write jq file with key value on sub object

Tags: json, bash, object, jq

I want to create a Json file (Composer) with JQ from nothing.
My objective is to set module and version from args passed in jq command

```
{
    "require" : {
        "mymodule": "myversion"
   }
}
```

I tried something like this and I don't understand why it's not correct.

```
jq --arg module "themodule" --arg version "3.0" '{.require.($module):$version}'
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

First, you will almost certainly want to use the `-n` command-line option; second, `module` is a keyword and so cannot be used as a $-variable name.  But:

```
jq -n --arg m themodule --arg version "3.0" '
  {require: { ($m): $version} }'
```

produces:

```
{
  "require": {
    "themodule": "3.0"
  }
}
```

The trick here is to enclose the expression specifying the key-name in parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! :)